# event delegate (in)equality?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, operators, inequality

Could someone explain the meaning of the following portion of code :

```
private event UserChangedHandler m_UserChanged;
public event UserChangedHandler UserChanged
{
  add
  {
      if (m_UserChanged != value)
      {
        m_UserChanged += value;
      }
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add { }` is a construct much like `get { }` for properties, except add works on events. You're defining custom functionality here when adding delegates to an event.

In this case, this method body prevents **consecutive** duplicates (i.e. you can't register the same method/handler twice **in a row**).

So in this example:

```
public void HandlerUserChanged(object o, UserChangedEventArgs args)
{
     // some code
}

public void HandlerUserChanged2(object o, UserChangedEventArgs args)
{
     // some code
}
```

Later:

```
UserChanged += HandleUserChanged;
UserChanged += HandleUserChanged;
UserChanged(this, new UserChangedEventArgs());
```

The method `HandleUserChanged` will only fire once, even though you registered it twice. A normal event (without the `add { }`) would invoke the function twice.

However:

```
UserChanged += HandleUserChanged;
UserChanged += HandleUserChanged2;
UserChanged += HandleUserChanged;
UserChanged(this, new UserChangedEventArgs());
```

Will allow `HandleUserChanged` to fire twice, because the last-registered handler isn't ever the one being added. The == operator on events works on the LAST handler. **(Thankyou to Matthew for bringing that to attention)**

Comment: Although, the code above will not stop you from adding the same method twice.  If you add a method A and a method B to the UserChanged event you can still add method A again.

Comment: @Matthew Manela: You're right, It'll only prevent consecutive adds. Still early in the morning, thankyou for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as odd that m_UserChanged is declared as an event rather than just a delegate instance (is that the right terminology...I get confused w/ delegates).  Events are analogous to a simple Property model in that they essentially wrap underlying fields within a pair of transparent methods.

The way I understand it, .Net allows for the creation of implcit (anonymous?) event and properties by taking something like this :

```
public int Value { get; set;}
public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
```

and then creating the respective underlying placeholder objects to generate something more like this:

```
private int _Value;
public int Value { get { return _Value;} set { _Value = value;}}

private EventHandler _ValueChanged;
public event EventHandler ValueChange { add { _ValueChanged += value;} remove { _ValueChanged -= value;}}
```

The underlying object can be defined explicitly of course, but what the code sample above looks like is a bit of a conflation between explicit and implicit event declaration...it looks like the following is actually being done (behind the scenes, as it were):

```
private UserChangedHandler _m_UserChanged; 
private event UserChangedHandler m_UserChanged { add { _m_UserChanged += value;} remove { _m_UserChanged -= value;}}
public event UserChangedHandler UserChanged 
{ 
  add 
  { 
      if (m_UserChanged != value) 
      { 
        m_UserChanged += value; 
      } 
  } 
}
```

It doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things, I don't guess, but it looks like an oversight.